# Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin in angular 5 from Client side

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, access-control

I am using httpClient angular package for get requests. I am using https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetValidPrimaryCurrencyCodes url for fetching data. It is giving CORS error in console.

I don't have access to server side code, but still I want to enalbe CORS in angular service. This is my service function

```
myfunction() {
  let head = new HttpHeaders();
  head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
  head.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  return this.http.get("https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetValidPrimaryCurrencyCodes", {headers: head}).toPromise();
}
```

**I have tried it with [chrome cors extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), and it works fine. But I want this to be enabled from angular code.**

I have also tried working with proxies, following [tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md). BUt it is still not working. This is my object in **proxy.conf.json** file.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://www.independentreserve.com/Public/GetValidPrimaryCurrencyCodes",
    "secure": false
  },
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

and added **"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"**  in package.json file. It is not working this way either.

Can any body give me some solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set response headers on client, only the server can do that. Ie. if you can't change the server side, your only option is adding a proxy server that you control in between.

Comment: I have tried it with proxy as mentioned. Is it correct way?

Comment: That's not a proxy server, you're just telling angular to swap the baseurl of all http requests it makes.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy